# Get the number of elements in a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

Is there any other way to get the number of elements in a 2D array, without using the if statement to remove the zeroes from output?

```
int array2d [3] [3] = { {1,2}, {4}, {7,8,9} };
for(int i=0;i<sizeof array2d/sizeof array2d[0];i++){
    for(int j=0;j<sizeof array2d[i]/sizeof array2d[i][0];j++){
        if(array2d[i][j]==NULL){
            continue;
        }else printf("%d", array2d[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

OUTPUT: 120
        400
        789

Comment: C have no concept of "null values". The symbol `NULL` is a null *pointer*.

Comment: There's no other way to do that.  The way you find out how many elements a *terminated* array contains is by iterating the array and counting elements until you find the terminator.

Comment: And an array will always have a fixed size, there's no way around it. If you want to keep track of "unused" elements through a sentinel value (like zero) then you need that condition to check for that value.

Comment: Ok thank you anyways.